# How do I get IE to properly reposition an element after a sibling resizes vertically?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, clearfix

I have the following markup:

```
<nav id='tab_links'>
  <a href='#view1'>One</a>
  <a href='#view2'>Two</a>
</nav>
<div id='container'>
  <div id='view1'>Short Content</div>
  <div id='view2'>Much longer content</div>
</div>
<footer>
 <input type='submit' />
</footer>
```

and the following styles:

```
#view2 { display: none; }
#footer { display: block; clear: both; text-align: right; }
#footer * { display: inline-block; text-align: center; }
```

I use the following jQuery to swap out the views:

```
$('#tab_links a').click(function() {
  var tabToShow = $($(this).attr('href'));
  var otherTabs = tabToShow.siblings();
  tabToShow.show();
  otherTabs.hide();
});
```

When I swap out the `view1` content for the `view2` content, the footer stays where it was, hovering above the middle of the new content. If I hover the mouse over the footer content, it jumps down into place. If I then revert the content back to `view1`, the footer again stays where it was for `view2`, which is far below the end of the `container`.

What styles can I apply to make IE reposition the footer appropriately? I've tried all of the following, in various combinations:

- apply `clearfix` to `#container`
- apply `clearfix` to `#footer`
- apply `height: auto` to `#container`
- apply `height: 30px` to `#footer input`
- apply `widgth: 100px` to `#footer input`

Comment: I also tried adding `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` inside the `#container`. This, too, fails to push the footer down when the content expands (or bring it up when it contracts). This leads me to suspect this cannot be a float problem.

Comment: I also tried chaining the hide/show events that toggle the views. `$('#view1').hide(0, function() { $('#view2').show(); });` behaves the same as $('#view1').hide(); $('#view2').show();`

Comment: This problem seems to be *very* closely related: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/force-ie-redraw (alas, it's unresolved)

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to treat it as a jQuery problem instead of a CSS problem.

First, define a `forceRedraw` function on jQuery elements that simply sets the element's class to its existing class:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  forceRedraw: function() {
    jQuery(this).each(function() {
      this.className = this.className;
    });
  }
});
```

Then, when swapping the views:

```
$('#view1').hide();
$('#view2').show();
$('#footer').forceRedraw();
```

(This solution was suggested on the [jQuery forums](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/ie))

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a simple "overflow: auto; width: auto;" applied on the #container will solve the problem.

See this: http://www.atbskate.com/trusktr/2010/03/05/clearing-floats-with-the-overflowauto-css-property/

Or this: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Was that the solution to your problem?

Comment: Sadly, this does not seem to be the problem I'm having. The views themselves aren't floated (although they do have some content that is floated).

Comment: hmmmm... You said there are some floated content inside the #views... Perhaps apply the suggested fix to the #view1 and #view2 divs (and to any other content that has floating elements inside of it)?

Comment: ...to make all of them expand.

Comment: Editing and posting your whole code might help us figure out what' wrong!